# I can not stop/pause threads in ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have `ExecutorService` and start 2 thread.

```
    public class Test {

    private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    public void start() {
        threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    if (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                        try {
                            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            System.out.println("subject 1 stopped!");
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // restore interrupted status
                            return;
                        }
                        System.out.println("Hello!");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    if (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                        try {
                            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            System.out.println("subject 2 stopped!");
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // restore interrupted status
                            return;
                        }
                        System.out.println("By!");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void stop() {
        threadPool.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

In Main class I want stop one Thread

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Start");
        Test test = new Test();
        test.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        test.stop();
    }
}
```

How can I STOP/PAUSE certain thread?

Comment: `sleep` throws InterruptedException. This resets the interrupted status. To use the status in the if like you do, you'd have to set the interrupted status again. => `} catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace(); Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        }`

Comment: I eddit quation

Comment: Oh, and actually you start 3 Threads. But that aside: "pausing" Threads is not a good idea and these methods have been deprecated for a reason. To cancel a Task you can refer to "[FutureTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)"'s Documentation. As I recall, there should even be an example. What are you trying to do, btw?

Comment: And for the record: most people associate the term *thread pool* with certain specific properties; and might it find rather surprising that you use an ExecutorService to back that. So renaming your "thread pool" to "executorService" might help in not surprising your readers that much.

Comment: I have 3 buttons on a web page to launch the report generation. one button - one type of reporting. I want to make three more buttons to stop each process reporting. each type of reporting is performed in a separate thread.

Comment: OK, then I would suggest to implement the cancellation feature. You need to keep a reference to the Task in order to cancel it. But that should be a rather minor change. I wouldn't support pausing, though. Too much hassle. Just start over, when it has been cancelled.

Comment: Could you share an example of how to do it? or links

Comment: Thread.stop() shouldn't be used. instead you should set a flag or hold a lock which pauses the thread.

Comment: See: https://dzone.com/articles/interrupting-executor-tasks

Comment: You can't pause a certain Thread but you can pause and resume entire ThreadPoolExecutor. Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html page and PausableThreadPoolExecutor implementation